# How to modify standard analyzer to include #?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

Some characters are treated as delimiters like #, so they would never match in the query. What should be the custom analyzer configuration closest to standard to allow these characters to be matched ?

Answer (score 8):

1) Simplest way would be to use [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) with [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html).

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=lowercase&pretty' -d 'new year #celebration vegas'
```

which would give you

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "new",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "year",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "#celebration",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "vegas",
    "start_offset" : 22,
    "end_offset" : 27,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 4
  } ]
}
```

2) If you only want to preserve some special characters then, you could map them with [char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html), so that your text would be transformed into something else before `tokenization` takes place. This is more closer to `standard analyzer`. For e.g you can create your index like this

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "special_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "special_mapping"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "special_mapping": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "#=>hashtag\\u0020"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "tweet": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "special_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now for `curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=special_analyzer&pretty' -d 'new year #celebration vegas'`
custom analyzer will generate following tokens

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "new",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 3,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "year",
    "start_offset" : 4,
    "end_offset" : 8,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "hashtag",
    "start_offset" : 9,
    "end_offset" : 9,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "celebration",
    "start_offset" : 10,
    "end_offset" : 21,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  }, {
    "token" : "vegas",
    "start_offset" : 22,
    "end_offset" : 27,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 5
  } ]
}
```

so you can search like this

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "tweet": "#celebration"
    }
  }
}
```

you will also be able to search for only *celebration* because I have used unicode for space `\\u0020` otherwise we would always have to search with `#`

hope this helps!!

Comment: this was great even like 5 years later 10/10 thanks