# elasticsearch: cannot search for @ symbol

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

Our mapping looks like this:

```
mappings: {
    entry: {
        properties: {
            id: { type: 'string' },
            name: { type: 'string' },
            creationTimestamp: { type: 'date', format: 'date_time' },
            lastTimestamp: { type: 'date', format: 'date_time' }
        }
    }
}
```

There are docs that contain @ symbols in the name, like for example "@TITLE@_30". However, I am not able to search for the @ symbol. Searching for `name:*title*` or `name:*_30*` works fine, but when trying `name:*@title*` I get no results.

Which tokenizer do I have to use so that this is possible? What our end-users want to do is just case insensitive searches with wildcards.

**EDIT**

The query looks like this:

```
query: {
    filtered: {
        filter: {
            bool: {
                must: [{
                    range: {
                        creationTimestamp: {
                            gte: startdate.toISOString(),
                            lte: enddate.toISOString()
                        }
                    },
                    query: {
                        query_string: {
                            query: 'name:*title*' // e.g
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. we use es v1.7

**EDIT 2**
Tried the 2 options from [How to modify standard analyzer to include #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754057/how-to-modify-standard-analyzer-to-include) but they don't work for me.

Also tried the following:

```
settings: {
    analysis: {
        analyzer: {
            name_analyzer: {
                type: 'custom',
                tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                filter: ['test']
            }
        },
        filter: {
            test: {
                type: 'word_delimiter',
                preserve_original: true,
                type_table: ['@ => ALPHANUM']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this only gets results for `name:*@*` and any other query doesn't work

Comment: I've tried most of the tokenizers, but only the standard one is suitable for the searches the users want to do. Except of course from the aforementioned problem with the @ symbol

Comment: Do you think that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754057/how-to-modify-standard-analyzer-to-include answers your question? If you don't mind, I'd flag this as a duplicate of that

Comment: Let me try that solution

Comment: @MarioTrucco, I tried both but none works

Comment: Trying option 1 `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=lowercase&pretty' -d '@TITLE@_30'` returned `Warning: Couldn't read data from file "TITLE@_30", this makes an empty POST.`

Comment: this is an issue with `CURL` an `-d` starting with `@`. The equivalent `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?tokenizer=whitespace&filters=lowercase&pretty&text=@TITLE@_30' ` seems to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify standard analyzer to include #?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754057/how-to-modify-standard-analyzer-to-include)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152839/discussion-between-xeniasis-and-mario-trucco).